# Div element cannot be nested inside element label

Tags: html

I have searched in google this message:

element div cannot be nested inside label element. But I can't find anything.

This is my html:

```
 <div class="email-logo">
     <label>
         <div class="email-logo-image">
              <img src='/Beheer/Document/Download?documentID=@(Html.GebruikerContext().Klant.LogoID)' />
         </div>
         <div class="email-logo-button">
              @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "klant", Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
              <span>eigen logo</span>
        </div>
     </label>
 </div>
```

So my question is:

How to correct this?

Thank you

Comment: first of all, you have a mistype in you html, you missed a ">" after the <label>... after that, what that divs inside label do? are there only for styling reason? in that case you can use <span>s or <i>s or so on ;)

Comment: Why do you need the div inside the label? You can add the class directly to the image or use a span instead of a div. Depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need the divs, if you don’t try this.

```
<div class="email-logo">
 <label>
     <img src='/Beheer/Document/Download?documentID=@(Html.GebruikerContext().Klant.LogoID)'class="email-logo-image" />
     <span class="email-logo-button">
          @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "klant", Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
          <span>eigen logo</span>
    </span>
 </label>
<\div>
```

You also had a typo which was likely making your html error. ( No > to close label)